# kendo grid how to set the schema.model with a foreign key field

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, kendo-grid, kendo-combobox

need help about adding a new recort in a kendo grid.
I have a grid with a foreign key field. The grid is populated by a json data with subobject, returned from a webmethod. it looks like this:

```
[
{
"classe_iva": {
  "id_classe_iva": 5,
  "desc_classe_iva": "Esente",
  "note_classe_iva": null
},
"id_iva": 37,
"desc_iva": "bbb",
"codice_iva": "bbb",
"imposta": 2,
"indetr": 2,
"id_classe_iva": 5,
"note": "dddddfsf",
"predefinito": false,
"id_company": 4
},
{
"classe_iva": {
  "id_classe_iva": 6,
  "desc_classe_iva": "Escluso",
  "note_classe_iva": null
},
"id_iva": 52,
"desc_iva": "o",
"codice_iva": "jj",
"imposta": 1,
"indetr": 1,
"id_classe_iva": 6,
"note": "l",
"predefinito": false,
"id_company": 4
}
]
```

and this is the schema.model used in the kendo datasource:

```
model = {
    id: "id_iva",
    fields: {
        id_iva: { type: "string", editable: false },
        desc_iva: { type: "string" },
        codice_iva: { type: "string" },
        imposta: { type: "number" },
        indetr: { type: "number" },
        id_classe_iva: {type: "string"},
        note: { type: "string" },
        predefinito: { type: "boolean" },
        id_company: { type: "number" }
    }
}
```

.. and below is shown the grid columns format:

```
toolbar = [{
    name: "create",
    text: "Aggiungi nuova aliquota IVA"
}];
columns = [
        { field: "desc_iva", title: "Descrizione", width: 45 },
        { field: "codice_iva", title: "Codice", width: 45 },
        { field: "imposta", title: "Imposta", width: 45 },
        { field: "indetr", title: "Indetr", width: 45 },
        { field: "classe_iva.desc_classe_iva", title: "Classe IVA", width: 200, editor: categoryDropDownEditor, template: "#= classe_iva ? classe_iva.desc_classe_iva : 1 #", defaultValue: { id_classe_iva: 1, desc_classe_iva: "Acq. Intra-UE" } },
        { field: "note", title: "Note", width: 45 },            

        {
            command: [{
                name: "destroy",
                text: "Elimina",
                confirmation: "Sei sicuro di voler eliminare questa voce?"
            } ,              
            {
                name: "edit",                   
                text: {
                    edit: "Modifica",
                    update: "Aggiorna",
                    cancel: "Cancella"
                }
            }
            ]

        }
];
```

Theese settings works fine when i edit a row, and the grid shows the right content into the combobox field.
The problem is when i click on the "add new record" button, because when it tries to add a new row, it doesn't find the subobjects field "classe_iva".

if i change the column.field into this

```
{ field: "id_classe_iva", title: "Classe IVA", width: 200, editor: categoryDropDownEditor, template: "#= id_classe_iva ? id_classe_iva : 1 #", defaultValue: { id_classe_iva: 1, desc_classe_iva: "Acq. Intra-UE" } },
        { field: "note", title: "Note", width: 45 }
```

the add button works fine, but when the grid is loaded, the column id_classe_iva doesn't shows me the classe_iva.desc_classe_iva field...

how can i fix the issue??^?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to fix this issue, i used a workaround:

the error was thrown because, in the declaration of the field.template there where a not declared variable (classe_iva):

```
 { field: "id_classe_iva", title: "Classe IVA", width: 200, editor: categoryDropDownEditor, template: "#= classe_iva ? classe_iva.desc_classe_iva : 1 #", defaultValue: { id_classe_iva: 1, desc_classe_iva: "Acq. Intra-UE" } },
```

then, i declared a global variable

```
var classe_iva;
```

in this way, when i add a new record, the code doesn't throw any errors, and by the ternary if, the default value is set.

hope it will help someone.